# Weird graphical glitch when using the back button in safari on mobile devices

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

So I've been developing a mobile website for a client and I've run into some weird graphical glitches when using the back button on iOS devices.

This is happening sporadically after having navigated through the site and then used the back button on the browser to go back to the previous page.  As you can see in the image it leaves a bit of the page the user clicked the back button from just below the fold on the page when it finishes reloading.

here's a screen capture when this has happened.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/esObx.png

Does anybody have any idea how I can prevent this from happening?

Comment: I've tried adding `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache"><meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">` to the page and it still happens.  I'm very confused by this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this was happening. It appears to have only affected mobile safari on iOS4 devices.  iOS3 devices and iOS5 devices appear to be immune.

My solution was to hide all the elements on the effected page and use setTimeout to wait a few microseconds before showing them to force a screen redraw.